# Removed item does not affect the total

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple expense calculator with javascript. Everything looks good except one thing.

When I delete something on expense history the deleted item does not affect total number.

When I add something from input box positive or negative it affects as usual but deleted history items don't affect the total.

```html
<body>
<h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
<div class="container">
    <p>Total : <span id="total"></span></p>
    <input id="inputField" type="number"><button id="addToDo">+</button>
    <div class="to-dos" id="toDoContainer">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  let totalspan = document.getElementById('total');
  let addToDoButton = document.getElementById('addToDo');
  let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
  let inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');
  var total = 0

  addToDoButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
      paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-styling');
      if (inputField.value > 0){
        paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(inputField.value)
      } else if (inputField.value < 0){
        paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(inputField.value)
      }
      totalspan.innerText = parseInt(total)
      toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
      inputField.value = "";
      paragraph.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
        toDoContainer.removeChild(paragraph);
      })
  })
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Assuming it's the `dblclick` handler that removes items: it's not changing the total because it makes no attempt to change the total; all it does is remove the paragraph.  I'd suggest separating the "calculate the total" part into its own function, and have both event handlers call it after adding or removing the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS is not reactive, so that you have to change the value in your `totalspan`

```html
<body>
<h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
<div class="container">
    <p>Total : <span id="total"></span></p>
    <input id="inputField" type="number"><button id="addToDo">+</button>
    <div class="to-dos" id="toDoContainer">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  let totalspan = document.getElementById('total');
  let addToDoButton = document.getElementById('addToDo');
  let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
  let inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');
  var total = 0

  addToDoButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
      paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-styling');
      if (inputField.value > 0){
        paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(inputField.value)
      } else if (inputField.value < 0){
        paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(inputField.value)
      }
      totalspan.innerText = parseInt(total)
      toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
      inputField.value = "";
      paragraph.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
        toDoContainer.removeChild(paragraph);
        total -= +paragraph.innerHTML;
        totalspan.innerHTML = total;
      })
  })
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the codes to update `totalspan.innerText` with latest value if double click one expense.

Check the comments (I added two lines of codes) in below fiddle.

```html
<body>
<h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
<div class="container">
    <p>Total : <span id="total"></span></p>
    <input id="inputField" type="number"><button id="addToDo">+</button>
    <div class="to-dos" id="toDoContainer">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  let totalspan = document.getElementById('total');
  let addToDoButton = document.getElementById('addToDo');
  let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
  let inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');
  var total = 0

  addToDoButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
      paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-styling');
      if (inputField.value > 0){
        paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(inputField.value)
      } else if (inputField.value < 0){
        paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(inputField.value)
      }
      totalspan.innerText = parseInt(total)
      toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
      inputField.value = "";
      paragraph.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
        toDoContainer.removeChild(paragraph);
        total = total - parseInt(this.innerText) // update total
        totalspan.innerText = total // update dom with latest value
      })
  })
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems with your code:

1. You aren't re-calculating the total after you delete the item.
2. You have an if/then clause (inputField.value > 0) where it then executes the exact same code no matter which branch of the if/then executes. You should fix that.
3. It looks like you are adding an eventListener ('dblclick') within another eventListener. Not sure if that's a good idea or not. Seems like they are in conflict with each other.
4. You might want to have a separate function that re-calculates the total that you can call from either an add or delete event.